# Determine decimal separator in Excel withoug VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Very often I have to share files with other people that need to be filled by them.

Some of the data entered by my customers are numbers that need to be formatted in certain (locked) cells with TEXT function. The problem is that I do not know if customers have period or comma set as decimal separator in their regional settings (or Excel settings). I know that the problem can be easily solved with VBA, but .xlsm files are not an option. Also, the file needs to be compatible at least with Excel 2007!

I searched the web but it appears that there is no solution with pure Excel functions?!

I managed to circumvent this using the following approach:

1. I create (in hidden+locked cells or hidden sheet) three (workbook) named ranges

[image]

testNumber = 1.23 (not really necessary to be a named range)

sepDec => =IF( testNumber=VALUE(TEXT(testNumber,"0.00")),  ".",  "," )

and

sepTh => =IF(sepDec=".",  ",",  ".")

2. Elsewhere in the Workbook I use the TEXT function as

=TEXT(cellAddress, "#" & sepTh & "##0" & sepDec & "0000")

I wonder if there is a better and easier way, or have I missed something and MS has a solution?!

Comment: `TEXT(testNumber,"0.00")` returns `#VALUE!` when `,` is decimal separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `dec_sep` user defined name with formula `=MID(TEXT(1/2, "@"),2,1)` at workbook scope. Then use `dec_sep` as decimal separator in formulas. Thus, unknown decimal separator character can be used.

**UPD**

The formula `=FIXED(1000+1/2)` returns both the separators. Extracting separators:

- For thousand separator `pos_sep` use `=MID(FIXED(1000+1/2),2,1)`
- For decimal separator `dec_sep` use `=MID(FIXED(1000+1/2),6,1)`

Thus, unknown decimal and thousand separator characters can be determined and used in formulas.

Comment: Suggested solution is practically the same as suggested in the question, except it allows for unknown decimal separator. But, I can not think of any situation when somebody would use decimal separator other than . or , ?

Comment: @user3560520, did you consider the localized versions of Excel? In the localized version, `.` may server as another separator. Thus the formulas depending on `.` as a decimal separator won't work. More over, the user may set particularly any character as a decimal, thouthand and list separator.

Comment: @user3560520, yes, in general case, the decimal separator is unknown. So, the solution should be for a general case.

Comment: `@AlekseyF` thanks for your suggestion and I'll accept your solution.
Your formula determines the decimal separator correctly, while my approach is less general and relies on the assumption that only `.` and `,` can be used as dec. separator.
However, although it is not in the title, the thousand separator needs to be determined as well!
Again, in a scenario when only `.` and `,` are used for dec. separator, I will use the "other" separator as the thousand one, regardless of system settings
And finally, my question includes **is there better and easier way?**
So far I've not found one!

Comment: @rtO, _"is there better and easier way?"_ Yes, done: see the update.

Comment: @AlekseyF. I have struggled with this for quite a while, thanks for introducing me to the "FIXED" function that I didn't know about. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will report which decimal separator is used:
=IF(IFERROR(VALUE("0,1");-1) < 0;"POINT";"COMMA")

Answer (score 0):

If all you do with the Text() function is format a number, and if the cells are locked, anyway, you might as well put the number into the cell and format the cell with the desired number format. Then Excel will take care of the rest when the file is opened on a machine with a different decimal separator.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not trivial.
Magnitude of the data in question is not known in advance and therefore the number format need to be dynamic - for example, "#,##0" or "0.000".
Furthermore, there are cells that contain numbers, dates and other information, so the only way to combine these values is by using the TEXT function

Answer (score 0):

I realize this a quite old thread, but I would just like to point out an alternative to the "TEXT" function.
For a similar problem I am using conditional formatting based on the cell content.

`=not(isnumber(A3)) -> Format as text`

`=A3<10 -> Format 0.000`

`=A3<1000 -> Format 0.00`

`and as default format #,##0.0`

This way you don't have to worry about the decimal or throusands symbol, because you pre-define the format.

Comment: Even though the suggested solution would work it is quite more complicated. One has to do 3 operations (Cond formatting) in every cell! My original solution serves the purpose in most cases, and the solution provided by @AlekseyF even improves it in both simplicity and general use.

Comment: In my previous comment I forgot to write:  Furthermore, formatting cells that have only numbers is trivial, however the problem arises when you have to combine text and numbers (with TEXT function) like `=A1 & TEXT(B1,"0.000")`. In those situations Cond. formatting doesn't help!